# Do respawned enemies give experience?

Tags: diablo-ii

In the early game of Diablo II I seem to be constantly facing these pesky Demon Shamans that endlessly respawn/resurrect nearby fallen demons.  I recall there are similar enemies later in the game that respawn different type of enemies.  I observe that the respawned versions don't seem to ever drop loot.  Am I getting experience for killing these respawned enemies, or, to add insult to injury literally - are they just a waste of time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[DiabloWiki](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Experience#Miscellaneous_Exp_Info) provides a good explanation:

**For resurrected monsters**, (by shamans (e.g., Fallen, Mummies, and Fetishes))you only get experience from killing a monster the first time.

**For monsters produced by monster generators** (e.g., Foul Crows, Zombies, and Imps), they are worth experience, but very little and do not drop any items. However, The generators themselves are worth good experience.

**For [Reanimated horde zombies](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Reanimated_Horde)**, they are worth full experience and may drop items when they resurrect themselves. Each kill counts for the full amount.

Additionally, **Monsters killed by another, under Convert, Confuse, or other related skills**, award their experience to the character who cast the spell on them.

Comment: I don't *think* spawners give EXP either, but I don't *know* one way or the other for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Resurrected minions are a complete waste of time. Dead Fallen that are resurrected by Fallen Shamans give no reward whatsoever for killing them again. The same is true of the skeletons in Act 2 who can be respawned by those mummy-type fellas.

Unfortunately, I don't know for sure how exactly experience works for enemies that *spawn* new enemies altogether. For example, the giant cockroaches in Act 2 can spawn baby cockroaches; I don't know whether they give experience or not.