# Do minions summoned by other enemies or bosses give XP?

Tags: diablo-iii

Enemies such as The Tomb Guardian will summon skeletons during battle. Do these minions give XP when they are killed?

Comment: Related; http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65229/do-respawned-enemies-give-experience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Skeletons summoned by the Tomb Guardian give both XP and can also drop items and gold.

It's a nice bonus, to be sure, but given the slow rate it takes for Tomb Guardians to summon more of their friends, you'll have better gold and XP rates if you just kill them and press on.

As far as I'm aware (and in my own experience), all summoned monsters give xp. Most summoned monsters can drop loot too, with the exception of boss adds (or if they do, it gets added to the boss' loot).

Comment: Is this true for all spawners, or just Tomb Guardians?

Comment: @Rachel So far, I've determined that boss adds don't give loot. All spawned enemies give xp, though.

Comment: I've noticed my XP bar moving when killing boss spawns. At least on Queen Araneae, one of the giant spiders, on Hell difficulty.

Comment: I have levelled up during boss fights by killing summoned adds.

Answer (score 0):

Most summoned creatures now give no exp. Mainly just the first summoned wave will give exp and then the rest will give no exp or loot.

However, when new encounters are added you will find where this is broken sometimes. Usually it is hot fixed shortly after the exploit/bug is found.